# How to define a function type in typescript with a variable argument name limited to keys of some interface

Tags: typescript

I want to define a Setter function type for an interface.
I expect it to look like this:

```
type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, [s: U]: T[U])
```

But this throws an error:

```
Type 'T[U]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator
```

the idea is to have a function type where the argument name is limited to certain possible values (in the case of a Setter it would be the keys of the interface the Setter is for)

I also tried:

```
type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, [s: string]: T[U]) => T
```

Error:

```
Type 'T[U]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)
```

however when I tried:

```
type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, []: T[U]) => T // no error
```

Which is working but obviously there is no restriction on the argument name in this case.

Here is a usage example:

```
export const setSku: ISetter<IProduct, "sku"> = (
  self: IProduct,
  sku: ISkuProjection
) => {
  return {} as IProduct
}
// sku is a key on the IProduct interface
// I want to restrict the argument names to [self and "sku"]
```

How can I achieve this? Is it even possible in Typescript?

Comment: You want the parameter name to be based on the key ? This is not possible in TS atm. you can just define the name in the general way and tie it to the type of the property `type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, value: T[U]) => T `, add in the property name if necessary `type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, name: U, value: T[U]) => T` (in case we need to knowthe actual prop to update)

Comment: how come ```type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, []: T[U]) => T // no error``` is allowed.

Comment: Empty array deconstruction.. not particularly useful but allowed .. You could pass in an object with a single prop that is of the expected name `type ISetter<T, U extends keyof T> = (self: T, update: Pick<T, U>) => T`

Comment: I think then the one I suggested would be best for me. At least it allows any name. It would have been nice to have this functionality though. I wonder why they stopped at allowing "any name" and not taking it further to "any name which belongs to key of specified interface". Will continue to explore, thank you for your suggestions! Let me know if you find anything.

Comment: The parameter name isn't meaningfully part of the type of a function, since JavaScript doesn't have named parameters the way, say, [Python does](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments).  It's really part of the function implementation details.  Can you describe a scenario where having a function whose implementer chooses a different name for a parameter would lead to some kind of error or problem?